# What is the name of this flower (on a tree)?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Here is a photo of a big red flower-like structure on a tree on Lama Island, close to Hong Kong. Does anyone know the name of the tree and what the black "berries" are attached to the "flower"?

[image]

Comment: I think this may be an aril or arilode rather than a flower, but I cannot be sure (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aril)).  If you have or can get more pictures from different angles, also some shots of the leave and bark that would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE!  In addition to what @BryanHanson suggests, it could be helpful to [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/86208/what-is-the-name-of-this-flower-on-a-tree#) your question to include size estimates for both the red flower-like and the black egg-like structures.  Thanks! 